# Performance issues in Jetpack compose (Feels jarring and slower than usual)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

**Did anyone notice the jarring or lag in the jetpack compose apps?**

As a new jetpack compose learner and developer, I developed some simple projects and felt significant performance issues while scrolling or navigating my app. Then I find some sample apps that are developed by Google's own team. I ran all of them. There are total 9 sample projects.

1. Crane
2. Jetcaster
3. Jetchat
4. JetLagged
5. JetNews
6. JetSnack
7. JetSurvey
8. Owl
9. Reply

GitHub Link **[here](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main)**.

After download those sample app and run my emulator and my own smartphone, I notice the same performance and jarring issues.

Previously I developed apps using Java and XML and I'm not facing this type of prolems there.

**Why this happens and how can I solve this problem?**

Comment: You need to build the projects in Release mode in order to see their real performance, the "inspector info" generation that is always enabled in Debug flavors of Jetpack Compose have abysmal performance and slow the app down a lot.

Comment: I have also noticed very bad performance in Jetpack compose compared to XML